# Authentification with JGit 's PullCommand

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am using JGit and want to pull from the remote repository to my local repository.

The first approch was to clone the repository and that worked fine:

```
CredentialsProvider cp = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(username, password);
try (Git result = Git.cloneRepository()
    .setURI("http://172.20.1.2/team/myrepo.git")
    .setDirectory(new File("c:\\temp\\gittest"))
    .setCredentialsProvider(cp)
    .call()) {
        System.out.println("Having repository: " + result.getRepository().getDirectory());
    }
```

But after the second call the repository does not need to be cloned again. Therefore I thought I need to pull

```
Git git = Git.open(new File("c:\\temp\\gittest"));
git.pull().call();
```

But I get the following error:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: http://172.20.1.2/team/myrepo.git: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered
```

I do not know where I can pass the pull command the credentials.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass a `CredentialsProvider` to the `PushCommand` in the same way as with the `CloneCommand`.

For example:

```java
CredentialsProvider cp = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(username, password);
git.pull().setCredentialsProvider(cp).call();
```

All commands that connect to a remote repository, have a common base class: `TransportCommand`. And this class provides the means to specify authentication providers.

To learn more about authentication with JGit you may also want to have a look at the [JGit Authentication Explained](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/) article I wrote some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-jgit` you can configure credentials as a `<server>` in Maven `settings.xml`. Be sure the `<id>` matches host of Git server.